# What is the recommended way to pass in a connection string to class object from web app

Tags: .net, class-design

I have a class within my web application that handles all my database access. Currently I have a class property to which that I pass in the database connection string stored in the web.config. Is this the best way or is there a better method to use? Thanks.

Comment: I have assumed you are taking about a .NET application, so I have re-tagged your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a key into `appSettings` block of `web.config` file. For example:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="connectionString" value="Data Source=xxx;ID=yyy;Initial Catalog=zzz; Password=ppp;"/>
</appSettings>
```

Inside your code you can use this setting like following:

```
using System.Configuration;

.....
.....

private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];
```

This way is excellent when you should access your connection string from different modules in one solution.

Comment: Using the connectionStrings section of the config may be more natural and have a couple of advantages (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

If the connection string is mandatory (which it probably is, since we're talking a data access class), I personally prefer to pass in the connection string/connection settings object in the constructor of the class.

If you're creating an abstracted data access layer you might consider passing in a ConnectionStringSettings object instead in order to be able to use the [ADO.NET provider model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z.aspx) to create the right type of ADO objects based on the provider type of the connection.

Passing a settings object instead of a string also helps if you are using Dependency Injection. That way the object can be automatically resolved by the IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (and have seen), this is the most adopted approach for maintaining a connection string. So yes, I would say storing connection string in a `web.config` file is fine.